# Is there a function to construct a callable with just a variable containing the name of the class as a string?

Tags: php, class

I am trying to construct a callable using just a string containing the name of the class that function lives in.

I have tried the following:

```
$class_name = "RandomInt";

// MediaWiki uses setFunctionHook()
$parser->setFunctionHook( $class_name, [constant($class_name . '::class'), 'defineParser']);
```

It gave me the error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Parser::setFunctionHook() must be callable, array given.
```

Here is also a working example of what it would look like if I didn't have the 'string constraint':

```
$parser->setFunctionHook( 'RandomInt', [RandomInt::class, 'defineParser']);
```

Comment: The `::class` gets the class name. You already have the class name in your variable. Try `$parser->setFunctionHook( 'RandomInt', [$class_name, 'defineParser']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this sytax: `$parser->setFunctionHook( $func, [ __CLASS__, $func ], Parser::SFH_NO_HASH );`

Example:

```php
$parser->setFunctionHook('defineParser', [RandomInt::class, 'defineParser']);
```